# How to mark a radio button as checked with no action performed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, radio-button

I have a form with `CheckBox` and `RadioButton` controls. When people click on the buttons/boxes it saves the results to my DB. Later, I might want someone else to retrieve the form and make changes or continue using it.

When I pull the info back from the database into a new "search" form (that looks exactly like the form used to submit the data), I want the radio buttons to reflect the state they were in when the form was saved. So if a box was TRUE (checked) when saved, I want it to show TRUE (checked) on the new form.

HOWEVER, when I use

```
radiobutton.checked = True
```

It DOES mark my button as checked.... it ALSO acts like the button was clicked again. So I have duplicate results in my database. It will keep doing this every time the form is opened.

So, I want a way to mark the box as checked (the state it was in when saved) but NOT CAUSE THE EVENT AGAIN.

Here's an example:

```
str = "SELECT * from OpenEvents WHERE EventID = " & eventId & ""
    Dim cmd6 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd6.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        contactType = dr("ContactType").ToString
        abend = dr("Abend").ToString
        paged = dr("Paged").ToString
        shortSummary = dr("ShortSummary").ToString
        eventNotes = dr("EventNotes").ToString
        impacting = dr("Impacting").ToString
        L1Engaged = dr("L1Engaged").ToString
        L2Engaged = dr("L2Engaged").ToString
        managerEngaged = dr("ManagerEngaged")
        IncTicket = dr("IncTicket").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()

    If contactType = "Call" Then
        CallRadioButton.Checked = True
    ElseIf contactType = "IM" Then
        IMRadioButton.Checked = True
    ElseIf contactType = "Other" Then
        OtherRadioButton.Checked = True
    ElseIf contactType = "Alert" Then
        AlertRadioButton.Checked = True
    Else
    End If

    If abend = "True" Then AbendCheckBox.Checked = True
    If paged = "True" Then PagedYes.Checked = True
    ShortSummaryTextBox.Text = shortSummary
    DetailsTextBox.Text = eventNotes
    If impacting = "True" Then ImpactingYesRadioButton.Checked = True
    If L1Engaged = "True" Then L1YesRadioButton.Checked = True
    If L2Engaged = "True" Then L2YesRadioButton.Checked = True
    If managerEngaged = "True" Then ManagerYesRadioButton.Checked = True
    IncTicketTextBox.Text = IncTicket
```

Comment: I suggest you to create a boolean to be used at the load event. Start it as true and change it's result to false when it finishes loading the form. And at every radio/check actions you verify the value of the boolean, exiting the sub if the form is on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Click` event instead of `CheckedChanged` event.

Doing so, if you want to raise the event linked to the RadioButton you can use `PerformClick` instead of `Checked = True`.

If you want to change checked status without raising the event you can use `Checked = True`.

Here a little example:

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click, RadioButton2.Click, RadioButton3.Click
    Select Case sender.name
        Case Is = "RadioButton1"
            Me.Label1.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.Label2.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
            Me.Label3.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
        Case Is = "RadioButton2"
            Me.Label1.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
            Me.Label2.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.Label3.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
        Case Is = "RadioButton3"
            Me.Label1.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
            Me.Label2.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
            Me.Label3.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_ChangeSelected_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_ChangeSelected.Click
    Me.RadioButton1.Checked = True
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_PerformClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_PerformClick.Click
    Me.RadioButton1.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

If you click Btn_ChangeSelected RadioButton1 will be checked but no event will be raised.

If you click Btn_PerformClick RadioButton1 will be checked and RadioButton1.click event will be raised.

Comment: I did that, as you see above in my code. No matter what I tried if I used     checked = True it always also triggered the event. I ended up moving my code out of CheckedChanged event and into a MouseClick event. I used that because that's the sub it created when I clicked on the control from design view. Lesson learned. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Doonze It exactly so. If you use `RadioButton.Click` event to run a sub you can change the checked state of the RadioButton without effects but you'll be still able to run the sub by using `RadioButton.PerformClick`. Furthermore, you can handle more `RadioButton.Click` with the same sub while this isn't possible by using `RadioButton.CheckedChanged` event because the code would run twice (one for the deselected RadioButton and another for the selected RadioButton)

Answer (score 1):

Just to turn it into an answer:

Create a boolean to be used at the form load event. Start it's value as true by default and when the load finishes, set it's value to false.

At every radio/check event you check the value, if it's true just exit the sub, otherwise do whatever it's supposed to do.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the state of the radiobuttons at form closing event to my.settings and read all back on the form load event. This way you keep the last settings of your radiobuttons before exiting the program.

Comment: I believe that will still fire the `CheckChanged` event though

Comment: Yes it does, so the logic should go in the CheckedChanged event. Use a boolean and set it so the first time, at the form load event it doen't do anything but sets the boolean so the next time it does whatever needs to be done.

Comment: While it fires it, I have no code in the CheckedChanged event now, so it just does nothing. So it works just as I need it to! Due to the way this can be used, and that several people can have the same form open at the same time, a file for setting isn't my best solution. But that a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ended up moving my code from

```
_CheckedChanged
```

event, that was the default when clicking on the control from design view, to a

```
_MouseClick
```

event. Solved all my problems. Seems it was a bit silly that was the default, but lessons learned. And all working as I need now.

Thanks for all the input!!!